# Dont' see option to download/upload some SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I have a SSRS 2016 instances with 100s of reports on one of my server. I want to migrate these reports from this instance to an existing new instance which already has some reports for different business unit. So basically I am downloading all RDLs and uploading those to a new instance.

While working on this task, I found one weird thing while downloading reports was for some reports download option is not present. My question is how to download these reports and why am I seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had to give content manager explicitly to all the reports where download option was unavailable even though I was a site admin on that box along with content manager on parent folders of respective reports. This fixed the issue and I was able to see the download option now. It's strange when you have admin rights on entire site but still have to give rights to individual reports.